# Insert a row in the middle of existing data

Tags: node.js, google-sheets-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm trying to insert an empty row in the middle of the spreadsheet using `node.js` and `Google Sheets API v4`. I've been researching everywhere for past few days, but couldn't find any documentation about it.

Google Spreadsheet Documentation only talks about `.append()`, which appends a row **at the end** of the spreadsheet. This is not quite what I want haha.

Is there even a way to insert an empty row in the middle of the data??

---

So.. Here is what I edited so far.

```
function newRow() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return getAuthorizedClient().then(client => {
      const sheets = google.sheets({
        version: 'v4',
        auth: client
      });
      var requests = [];

      requests.push({
        insertDimension: {
          range: {
            sheetId: MY_SHEET_ID,
            dimension: 'row',
            startIndex: 50,
            endIndex: 1
          },
          inheritFromBefore: false
        }
      });
      var batchUpdateRequest = { requests: requests };

      sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate({
        spreadsheetId: CONFIG_SHEET_ID,
        resource: batchUpdateRequest
      });
    });
  });
}
```

`getAuthorizedClient` is a function I made for auth. Anyway, the problem I get here is

> Error: Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "requests": Cannot find field.

I'm not too sure what I'm doing wrong - I'm following straight from the Google API documentation.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#insertdimensionrequest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the Sheets API reference, to insert rows you need to send an [`InsertDimensionRequest`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#insertdimensionrequest) with a valid [`DimensionRange`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/DimensionRange) property.

Indeed, this part of your code is correct:

```
{
  insertDimension: {
    range: {
      sheetId: MY_SHEET_ID,
      dimension: 'ROWS',
      startIndex: 50,
      endIndex: 1
    },
    inheritFromBefore: false // Use start (true) or end (false) index to set defaults.
  }
}
```

(Though I believe you want to have your end index as `51` and not `1`. That would then insert a row at the 50th index, where Row 1 is index 0.)

From the error message

> Error: Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "requests": Cannot find field.

we can determine that your particular `batchUpdate` request has incorrect. syntax. Note that there are multiple classes in the Sheets API that implement a `batchUpdate` method: [`spreadsheets.batchUpdate`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate) and [`spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate). Only for the `batchUpdate` method of the `spreadsheets` resource is an array of input `Requests` a valid parameter - batch updates of the `values` resource requires a `data` parameter (i.e., the values to be written to the targeted cells).

Thus, the fix is to change the class used to construct the `batchUpdate` request:

```
function newRow(sheets, config, options) {
  var newRowRequest = {
    insertDimension: {
      range: {
        sheetId: options.sheetId,
        dimension: 'ROWS',
        startIndex: options.start,
        endIndex: options.start + options.howMany
      },
      inheritFromBefore: options.inheritBefore
    }
  };

  var batchUpdateRequest = {
    requests: [newRowRequest]
    // includeSpreadsheetInResponse: ...,
    // responseRanges: [...],
    // responseIncludeGridData: ...
  };
  return sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate({
    spreadsheetId: config.spreadsheetId,
    resource: batchUpdateRequest
  }); // Returns AxiosPromise
}
```

- [Node.js API reference for Sheets REST API](https://google.github.io/google-api-nodejs-client/modules/_apis_sheets_v4_.html).

  - [`spreadsheets.batchUpdate`](https://google.github.io/google-api-nodejs-client/classes/_apis_sheets_v4_.resource_spreadsheets.html#batchupdate)
  - [`spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate`](https://google.github.io/google-api-nodejs-client/classes/_apis_sheets_v4_.resource_spreadsheets_values.html#batchupdate)

Comment: Hey, Thank you so much for replying. One quick question: Can `sheetID`s for `insertDimension` and `sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate` be the same?

Comment: @YegeonSeo I'm not sure I understand your question - the node.js method `sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate` takes a Spreadsheet ID (technically the Google Drive file ID) as a parameter, which selects the workbook that should receive the supplied requests. Requests bundled into that `batchUpdate` request may take a Sheet ID that identifies the sheet within the workbook to which the request applies (such as `insertDimension` or `repeatCell`). https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/sheet

Comment: Aha, that makes sense. I also got mine working by following your sample code! Thank you so much.

Comment: I think it needs to be ` dimension: "ROWS",` rather than `dimension: "row"`

Answer (score -2):

Google Apps Script Documentation is pretty good for this sort of thing.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

// This inserts a row after the first row position.
sheet.insertRowAfter(1);
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you. One question though: How do you import SpreadsheetApp? I followed the set up guide and did `$ npm install googleapis@27 --save`, but not sure how I should import it in my code.

Comment: @YegeonSeo this answer is not for node.js, it uses features exclusive to the Google Apps Script environment. I commented a link to the relevant Sheets API update request. If you have problems implementing it, please edit your question and we can provide suitable recommendations / answers